# How to attach a message multiple times (say 200 times) with the tangle using MAM

Tags: iota-network, masked-authenticated-messaging, javascript

What I am trying to do is to attach a payload to the tangle using MAM protocol. If I run this loop for k=5 times it works fine i.e., data is attached to the Tangle. I confirmed that the data is attached by writing fetching code as well and it works fine.
However, when I try to increase loop counter greater than 5 it gives me an error "Failed to attach message".
I want to know what's wrong in the code. I have used different test nodes as well to make it work but it's not working.

`var now = require("performancenow")
const math = require('mathjs')
const Mam = require('./lib/mam.client.js')
const { asciiToTrytes, trytesToAscii } = require('@iota/converter')
const IOTA = require('iota.lib.js')
const iota = new IOTA({
      provider: 'https://dyn.tangle-nodes.com:443'
    })
var k;
for (k = 0; k <200; k++){
    //seed generator
const generate = require('iota-generate-seed');
 seed = generate();
    //key
const key='mysecret'
//Channel mode
const type = 'restricted'
// Initialise MAM State
let mamState = Mam.init(iota, seed, 2)
// Set channel mode
mamState = Mam.changeMode(mamState, type, key)
// Callback used to pass data out of the fetch
const logData = data => console.log(JSON.parse(trytesToAscii(data)))
const publish =  async (packet, i) => {
    // Create MAM Payload - STRING OF TRYTES
    const trytes = iota.utils.toTrytes(JSON.stringify(packet))
    const message = Mam.create(mamState, trytes)
        // Save new mamState
    mamState = message.state
    // Attach the payload.
    await  Mam.attach(message.payload, message.address)
        const logData = trytes => console.log(JSON.parse(iota.utils.fromTrytes(trytes)))
    console.log("Payload: "+packet, "Payload in trytes: "+ asciiToTrytes(packet))
 } //end of async
publish('0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789', k) 
 }//end of k loop`